# Cannot execute gcc due to "permission denied"

Tags: permissions, gcc

So I was thinking about learning some C this week, so I went to setting up everything. I was checking to make sure I had `gcc` installed using `gcc -v`, and I got the error

```
bash: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied
```

After this, I tried the same command using sudo, but got the error

```
sudo: gcc: command not found
```

If it's relevant, my Linux version is Pop_OS! 20.04 LTS, running kernel 5.8.0-7630-generic.

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: My gcc is a symbolic link: `/usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-5`. /usr/bin/gcc-5 is a 1MB executable. It seems likely your install is incomplete.

Comment: What should I do to resolve this? Is there any information I can provide that would help discover whatever the problem may be with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a little digging, I managed to discover which `gcc` version was installed by using the command 
`ls /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu`

This revealed a folder called `9`, and assuming this was the version of `gcc` installed, I used 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-9`

Following this, `gcc -v` worked fine without sudo.